# MySQL Select And Order DateTime Ascending But Have Expired TImes at the Bottom of the Query

Tags: mysql, database

I need to figure out how to get all datetimes in the query order ascending but put the expired datetimes below the non expired ones.

```
"select * from users where date > now()"
```

Comment: Show us what you've got so far. Hint: ORDER BY date > NOW()

Comment: I already know about now(). I just need to be able to get the rest of the times, the expired ones, but put them at the bottom.

Comment: ah, so i should use order and not where, thanks ;)

Comment: yes - although you could also look at UNION

Comment: @Strawberry thankyou :D, UNION did the trick i needed. I can use my where clause with it and much more, Thankyou straberry :)

Comment: i just did some research and they say union is like double the load. i'll try to figure out how to avoid union if possible.